# Why does ";;;;;" compile?

Tags: c#

Just wondering why several ";;" in a C# statement don't throw an error while compiling, e.g.

```
string todayDate = DateTime.Now.ToString(); ;;;;; ;
```

Comment: well... why *should it* ?

Comment: dont get it too, why it's criminal? :) an empty statement has no conficts with language syntax

Comment: @MarcGravell - Personally,;: I don'''t, fin;d it at al?:l over.kill. :)

Comment: `for(;;) == while(true)`

Comment: @Sayse Maybe it's a special case, because the middle empty "position" is not a statement, and the last empty statement is missing its semicolon. You can also use `for(;true;)`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - Was just providing somewhere you may wish to use an empty statement (I still think its harder to read than the while loop)

Comment: @Sayse Yeah, good example. Most of the time where you can use an empty statement, it looks better to use an empty block, so for example `while (b) { }` looks better that `while (b) ;`. If you change from `while` to `if` here, the last example with the empty statement even emits a compiler warning.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because `;` is a valid **[empty statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)** in C# language.

[The empty statement - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> An empty statement is used when there are no operations to perform in
>   a context where a statement is required.
>
> Execution of an empty statement simply transfers control to the end
>   point of the statement. Thus, the end point of an empty statement is
>   reachable if the empty statement is reachable.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the compiler interprets it as empty code lines.

Answer (score 0):

Why should it?

Just a bunch of empty statements in a row.

No syntax error, no semantic error, nothing but a programmer writing a bunch of placeholder lines.